# What is the best way to achieve this effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

What is the best way to achieve this effect in Photoshop?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are often many ways to do the same thing in Photoshop, none are specifically the "best". Use which ever method you like.

Anyway, here's one method

Choose black as the foregournd colour, and a bright background colour

[image]

Add a gradient map adjustment layer, and select the Foreground to Background gradient.

[image]

Add a levels adjustment layer, pull up the blacks, and pull down the whites

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good way!